# Practical example for Immutable class

Tags: java, immutability

It is obvious that immutability increases the re-usability since it creates new object in each state change.Can somebody tells me a practical scenario where we need a immutable class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider `java.lang.String`. If it weren't immutable, every time you ever have a string you want to be confident wouldn't change underneath you, you'd have to create a copy.

Another example is collections: it's nice to be able to accept or return a genuinely immutable collection (e.g. from Guava - not just an immutable view on a mutable collection) and have confidence that it won't be changed.

Whether those count as "needs" or not, I don't know - but I wouldn't want to develop without them.

Comment: Looks like you hit 400k today, congrats!

Comment: Thanks :) 500k by the end of the year?

Comment: Actually I was looking for a situation where we need to implement an immutable class.(not in java api. in a project)

Comment: @Jon They have to remove the daily 200-limit so that you will be a millionaire by the end of the year!

Comment: @esudharaka, the same advantages apply to code you write as to `String`: you don't have to worry about it changing out from under you; thread safety guarantees and invariants become much easier to reason about, and your life is generally less of a pain.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: If they removed the rep cap limit retrospectively, I'd have a bit over 1.3M...

Comment: @esudharaka: What Louis said, basically. If you want to feel the difference, use Joda Time's immutable date/time API for a while, then go back to Calendar and Date...

Answer (score 3):

A good example is related to hashing.  A class overrides the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods so that it can be used in data structures like HashSet and (as keys in) HashMap, and the hash code is typically derived by some identifying member attributes.  However, if these attributes were to change then so would the object's hash code, so the object is no longer usable in a hashing data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Java provides a nice example: `String`.